# need help optimized sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a web site that tracks mutual fund investment. for this I have below table structure (structure has been modified to remove unwanted columns so as to bring focus on my problem)

**Table #1: scheme_Mst**

```
|Scheme_ID | fundHouse_Id | OpeningBalance | OpeningUnits
----------------------------------------------------------
|1         |  1           | 100            |  10
```

**Table #2 investment**

```
|Scheme_ID | InvestedAmt   | InvestedUnits | statusFlag
----------------------------------------------------------
|1         | 50            |  5            | A
```

**Table #3 redemption**

```
|Scheme_ID | redemedAmt    | redemedUnits  | statusFlag
----------------------------------------------------------
|1         | 50            |  5            | A
```

**Table #4 SwitchDetails**

```
|From_Scheme_ID |To_Scheme_ID |switchInAmt |switchInUnits |switchOutAmt |switchOutUnits | StaFlag
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1              | 2           | 20         | 2            | 10          | 1             | A
```

**Table #5 BonusDetails**

```
|Scheme_ID | BonusAmt   | BonusUnits | statusFlag
----------------------------------------------------------
|1         | 50         |  5         | A
```

**Table #6 Divident_Detais**

```
|Scheme_ID | DividentAmt | DividentUnits | statusFlag
----------------------------------------------------------
|1         | 50          |  5            | A
```

Now to have a details of the of available units in the scheme I have below query ....(Which is very very expensive )

```
SELECT *,
       CASE
           WHEN OutstandingUnits <> 0 THEN CONVERT(decimal(18,2),Outstanding/OutstandingUnits)
           ELSE 0
       END AS WAC
FROM
  (SELECT *,
          ISNULL(OpeningBalance,0) + ISNULL(DividendAmount,0) + ISNULL(bonusAmount,0) + ISNULL(invstAmount,0) + ISNULL(SwitchedInAmount,0) - ISNULL(redeemedAmount,0) - ISNULL(SwitchedOutAmount,0) AS Outstanding,
          ISNULL(openingUnits,0) + ISNULL(DividendUnits,0) + ISNULL(bonusUnits,0) + ISNULL(invstUnits,0) + SNULL(SwitchedInUnits,0) - ISNULL(redeemedUnits,0) - ISNULL(SwitchedOutUnits,0) AS OutstandingUnits
   FROM
     (SELECT C.scheme_ID,D.schemeName, D.Openingbalance AS OpeningBalance, D.OpeningUnits AS openingUnits, ISNULL(SUM(C.invstAmount),0) AS invstAmount, ISNULL(SUM(C.invstUnits),0) AS invstUnits,
        (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(redemedAmt),0)
         FROM redemption
         WHERE StatusFlag='A'
           AND scheme_ID = C.scheme_ID) AS redeemedAmount,
        (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(redeemedUnits),0)
         FROM redemption
         WHERE StatusFlag='A'
           AND scheme_ID = C.scheme_ID) AS redeemedUnits,
        (SELECT ISNULL(sum(switchOutAmt),0)
         FROM SwitchDetails
         WHERE BB.Status = 'A'
           AND BB.From_Scheme_Id = C.scheme_ID) AS SwitchedOutAmount,
        (SELECT ISNULL(sum(switchOutUnits),0)
         FROM SwitchDetails
         WHERE BB.Status = 'A'
           AND BB.From_Scheme_Id = C.scheme_ID) AS SwitchedOutUnits,
        (SELECT ISNULL(sum(switchOutAmt),0)
         FROM SwitchDetails
         WHERE BB.Status = 'A'
           AND BB.From_Scheme_Id = C.scheme_ID) AS SwitchedInAmount,
        (SELECT ISNULL(sum(SwitchedInUnits),0)
         FROM SwitchDetails
         WHERE BB.Status = 'A'
           AND BB.From_Scheme_Id = C.scheme_ID) AS SwitchedInUnits, .. same way
      FOR bonus
      AND divident ..
      FROM Investment c) tab)tab2
```

This query is supposed to produce the below output.. (sample output)

```
Scheme_ID| Scheme_Name | OpeningBalance | OpeningUnits | InvstAmount | invstUnits | redemedAmount | redemedUnits | SwitchedOutAmt | SwitchOutUnit | bonusAmt | bonusUnit | DividentAmount | DividentUnit | Outstanding | OutstandingUnit | WAC
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is how I am calculating the details. Please suggest me the better way of doing it.

I am using sql server 2008

Comment: You need use joins , not subqueries

Comment: The `where` on each of the subqueries from `SwitchedOutAmount` onwards have nothing to do with the `SwitchDetails` tables they reference - so the numbers are going to `sum` the entire table...

Comment: If you have many parallel 1-N relations, then you probably have to use subqueries (grouping may duplicate rows) - but even then you can always aggregate many values in single (sub)query, like "select sum() as a1, sum() as as2, ... from ...".

Comment: you can create a flat view of the data or [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) for sql server.

Comment: Thanks all for your time will try with joins and get back.

Comment: when working in a query where you say 
    select * from (select * from table) as x 
you're actually no longer working with tables but with views, use inner joins for adding performance. Add indexes on the tables will also fasten up the query, only select the fields that are needed, the rest will ask extra memory etc...

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries with the same conditions are probably the worst performance enemies in this case.

Try this for your inner query:

```
SELECT 
    c.scheme_ID,
    d.schemeName,
    d.Openingbalance AS OpeningBalance,
    d.OpeningUnits AS openingUnits,
    ISNULL(SUM(c.invstAmount), 0) AS invstAmount,
    ISNULL(SUM(c.invstUnits), 0) AS invstUnits,

    ISNULL(SUM(r.redemedAmt), 0) AS redeemedAmount,
    ISNULL(SUM(r.redeemedUnits), 0) AS redeemedUnits, 
    ISNULL(SUM(r.switchOutAmt), 0) AS SwitchedOutAmount,
    ISNULL(SUM(r.switchOutUnits), 0) AS SwitchedOutUnits,
    ISNULL(SUM(r.switchOutAmt), 0) AS SwitchedInAmount,
    ISNULL(SUM(r.SwitchedInUnits), 0) AS SwitchedInUnits
FROM Investment AS c
INNER JOIN redemption AS r 
    ON r.StatusFlag='A' AND r.scheme_ID = C.scheme_ID
--INNER JOIN someTable AS d...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (I didn't insert `GROUP BY` clause or sum `Openingbalance, OpeningUnits` you know better your query logic, I edited just for performance):

```
SELECT *,
       CASE
           WHEN OutstandingUnits <> 0 THEN CONVERT(decimal(18,2),Outstanding/OutstandingUnits)
           ELSE 0
       END AS WAC
FROM
     (SELECT C.scheme_ID,
             D.schemeName, 
             D.Openingbalance AS OpeningBalance, 
             D.OpeningUnits AS openingUnits, 
             ISNULL(SUM(C.invstAmount),0) AS invstAmount, 
             ISNULL(SUM(C.invstUnits),0) AS invstUnits,
         ISNULL(SUM(r.redemedAmt),0) redeemedAmount,
         ISNULL(SUM(r.redeemedUnits),0) redeemedUnits,
         ISNULL(sum(sd.switchOutAmt),0) SwitchedOutAmount,
         ISNULL(sum(sd.switchOutUnits),0) SwitchedOutUnits,
         ISNULL(sum(sd.switchOutAmt),0) SwitchedInAmount,
         ISNULL(sum(sd.SwitchedInUnits),0) SwitchedInUnits,
          --The sum columns from above query
          ISNULL(OpeningBalance,0) + ISNULL(DividendAmount,0) + ISNULL(bonusAmount,0) + ISNULL(invstAmount,0) + 
          ISNULL(SwitchedInAmount,0) - ISNULL(redeemedAmount,0) - ISNULL(SwitchedOutAmount,0) AS Outstanding,
          ISNULL(openingUnits,0) + ISNULL(DividendUnits,0) + ISNULL(bonusUnits,0) + ISNULL(invstUnits,0) + 
          ISNULL(SwitchedInUnits,0) - ISNULL(redeemedUnits,0) - ISNULL(SwitchedOutUnits,0) AS OutstandingUnits,
          ----
      .. same way
      FOR bonus
      AND divident ..
      FROM Investment c
      LEFT JOIN redemption r
       ON r.StatusFlag='A'
       AND r.scheme_ID = C.scheme_ID
      LEFT JOIN SwitchDetails sd
       ON sd.Status = 'A'
       AND sd.From_Scheme_Id = C.scheme_ID
       ) tab
```